# Instagram account hacked, two factor authentication set up by hacker

Tags: instagram, account-recovery, authentication, multi-factor-auth, hacked

Apologies if I’m not posting this in the appropriate community.

Recently my sister’s email account was hacked and the hacker gained access to her Instagram account. We have gotten back into her email account and changed the password on it but we are locked out of her Instagram account.

The password and email address of the account was changed. Instagram support suggested clicking the links to “Secure your account” in the email notifying her about the change of email address but we went through her emails and the links are now all dead unfortunately.

After going through the account recovery process, we eventually made some progress. After clicking “Can’t reset your password” in the login screen, it asked if she had a photo of herself on her account, and we chose yes. (Presumably this is for the part where you are asked to take a video selfie of yourself to recover your account, as mentioned in the support article, but we didn’t get this far).

After providing a previous password for the account, it sent a confirmation code to her phone number, which we entered, but that was as far as we got. After that, a two factor authentication prompt came up asking for either a code from an authenticator app or a backup code.

She never set up two factor authentication on her account, so it seems like the hacker has set up two factor authentication on the account themselves. I did some research but I can’t seem to find a way to get past the two factor authentication or to contact Instagram and get a response from them.

Any advice on how to get past the two factor authentication or on how to contact Instagram would be appreciated. If we can we would also be fine with just getting the account shut down so they can’t use it to scam anyone, we’ve tried reporting it. Thanks